# ~~Loop dying in Python due to creating a new file~~ Read/Write Problem SOLVED

Tags: python

I am running a python file on a infinite loop when I start my PC. This script is saving data into a txt file and I am reading it to see if the data I'm getting I already got. I have tried many different read/write types, r+ w+ a+, if the file doesn't already exist ... the script stops. I am printing the contents of the text file and if it's not already created the loop prints nothing. This could also be a problem with .read()? I have tried using .seek(0) with no avail.

Here is the file write part of the code:

```py
def is_online_unique(streamer):
    file_contents = 'Null'
    is_online_new = False
    file_name = streamer + "Streams.txt"
    with open(r'D:\StreamerDates\\' + file_name , 'a+') as current_file:
      current_file.seek(0)

      r = requests.get(url=API_ENDPOINT+streamer, headers=head)

      data = r.text

      #print(data.replace('"', '').replace('\'', '').split(','))
      if 'type' in data and 'live' in data:
          clean_data = data.replace('"', '').replace('\'', '').split(',')
          for string in clean_data:
            if 'started_at' in string:
              date_started = string
              print("Date Started = " + date_started)
          try:
            file_contents = current_file.read()
          except:
            print('Error in reading file somehow :P')

          print("File contents:" + file_contents)
          if date_started in file_contents:
            is_online_new = False
          else:
            is_online_new = True

      if is_online_new:
        current_file.write(date_started + '\n')
      elif len(file_contents) > 500:
        if os.path.exists(r'D:\StreamerDates\\' + file_name):
          os.remove("demofile.txt")

      current_file.close()

    return is_online_new
```

in main:

```py
    while(True):
      for streamer in streamers:
        if is_online_unique(streamer):
          url = 'twitch.tv/' + streamer
          #print(streamer + "\'s stream opened")
          webbrowser.get(windowsChromePath).open(url)
```

Comment: There is no loop here, and a lot of irrelevant code. Please try and provide a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the file with

```
with open(r'D:\StreamerDates\\' + fileName , 'a+') as currentFile:
```

with the 'a+', that means you can append data to the file, not read, to read you will have to have another

```
with open(r'D:\StreamerDates\\' + fileName , 'r') as currentFile:
```

but with a 'r' so you can read the data in it

You also dont need a `currentFile.close()` as the `with` statement does that for you

---

turns out i was slightly wrong here 'a+' does read.
[link to modes](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61038544/)

I think the problem is that you are creating a new file, and writing to it the `datestarted` variable but only when `IsOnline is True`. `IsOnline` becomes true when `datestarted` is in the file. So its never going to write and the read will return nothing which is what i think you were seeing. its not wrong, there is just nothing in the file

Comment: Putting it in r+ says "There is no such file or directory" I need it to create the file if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a read/write problem. Hate how I have to check if the file exists and change my read/write mode because of it.